# zoneminder auto tracking zmtrack.pl modification to set PTZ maximum YX boundaries

Tags: perl, zoneminder

I am using zoneminder for security of the facility with a buch of cameras and also to record hockey games using a TrendNet TV-IP612P PTZ network camera.  I can control ptz movement with HTTP commands no problem.  I am using the auto tracking script (zmtrack.pl) that comes with zoneminder to track movement.  It works but I want to limit maximum YX range boundaries that the camera can pan and tilt. The camera is located at the center side of the ice rink at the ceiling.

I believe that by modifying the zmtrack.pl Perl script (see below) it could be possible to restrict pan and tilt X & Y values (I mean top,bottom, left and right).

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

```html
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
#
# ==========================================================================
#
# ZoneMinder Experimental PTZ Tracking Script, $Date: 2009-06-08 10:11:56 +0100 (Mon, 08 Jun 2009) $, $Revision: 2908 $
# Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Philip Coombes
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
#
# ==========================================================================
#
# This script is used to trigger and cancel alarms from external sources
# using an arbitrary text based format
#
use strict;
use bytes;

# ==========================================================================
#
# User config
#
# ==========================================================================

use constant SLEEP_TIME => 10000; # In microseconds

# ==========================================================================
#
# Don't change anything from here on down
#
# ==========================================================================

# Include from system perl paths only
use ZoneMinder;
use DBI;
use POSIX;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep );

$| = 1;

$ENV{PATH}  = '/bin:/usr/bin';
$ENV{SHELL} = '/bin/sh' if exists $ENV{SHELL};
delete @ENV{qw(IFS CDPATH ENV BASH_ENV)};

my $mid = 0;

sub Usage
{
    print( "
        Usage: zmtrack.pl -m <monitor>,--monitor=<monitor>]
        Parameters are :-
        -m<monitor>, --monitor=<monitor>   - Id of the monitor to track
        ");
    exit( -1 );
}   

if ( !GetOptions( 'monitor=s'=>\$mid ) )
{
    Usage();
}

logInit();
logSetSignal();

my ( $detaint_mid ) = $mid =~ /^(\d+)$/;
$mid = $detaint_mid;

print( "Tracker daemon $mid (experimental) starting at ".strftime( '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', localtime() )."\n" );

my $dbh = zmDbConnect();

my $sql = "select C.*,M.* from Monitors as M left join Controls as C on M.ControlId = C.Id where M.Id = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached( $sql ) or Fatal( "Can't prepare '$sql': ".$dbh->errstr() );

my $res = $sth->execute( $mid ) or Fatal( "Can't execute '$sql': ".$sth->errstr() );
my $monitor = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();

if ( !$monitor )
{
    print( "Can't find monitor '$mid'\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}
if ( !$monitor->{Controllable} )
{
    print( "Monitor '$mid' is not controllable\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}
if ( !$monitor->{TrackMotion} )
{
    print( "Monitor '$mid' is not configured to track motion\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}

if ( !$monitor->{CanMoveMap} )
{
    print( "Monitor '$mid' cannot move in map mode" );
    if ( $monitor->{CanMoveRel} )
    {
        print( ", falling back to pseudo map mode\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        print( "\n" );
        exit( -1 );
    }
}

Debug( "Found monitor for id '$monitor'\n" );
exit( -1 ) if ( !zmMemVerify( $monitor ) );

sub Suspend
{
    my $monitor = shift;
    zmMonitorSuspend( $monitor );
}

sub Resume
{
    my $monitor = shift;
    sleep( $monitor->{TrackDelay} );
    zmMonitorResume( $monitor );
}

sub Track
{
    my $monitor = shift;
    my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
    my ( $detaint_x ) = $x =~ /^(\d+)$/; $x = $detaint_x;
    my ( $detaint_y ) = $y =~ /^(\d+)$/; $y = $detaint_y;

    my $ctrlCommand = ZM_PATH_BIN."/zmcontrol.pl -i ".$monitor->{Id};
    $ctrlCommand .= " --command=".($monitor->{CanMoveMap}?"moveMap":"movePseudoMap")." --xcoord=$x --ycoord=$y";
    executeShellCommand( $ctrlCommand );
}

sub Return
{
    my $monitor = shift;

    my $ctrlCommand = ZM_PATH_BIN."/zmcontrol.pl -i ".$monitor->{Id};
    if ( $monitor->{ReturnLocation} > 0 )
    {
        $ctrlCommand .= " --command=presetGoto --preset=".$monitor->{ReturnLocation};
    }
    else
    {
        $ctrlCommand .= " --command=presetHome";
    }
    executeShellCommand( $ctrlCommand );
}

my $last_alarm = 0;
if ( ($monitor->{ReturnLocation} >= 0) )
{
    Suspend( $monitor );
    Return( $monitor );
    Resume( $monitor );
}

my $alarmed = undef;
while( 1 )
{
    if ( zmIsAlarmed( $monitor ) )
    {
        my ( $alarm_x, $alarm_y ) = zmGetAlarmLocation( $monitor );
        if ( $alarm_x >= 0 && $alarm_y >= 0 )
        {
            Debug( "Got alarm at $alarm_x, $alarm_y\n" );
            Suspend( $monitor );
            Track( $monitor, $alarm_x, $alarm_y );
            Resume( $monitor );
            $last_alarm = time();
            $alarmed = !undef;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( logDebugging() && $alarmed )
        {
            print( "Left alarm state\n" );
            $alarmed = undef;
        }
        if ( ($monitor->{ReturnLocation} >= 0) && ($last_alarm > 0) && ((time()-$last_alarm) > $monitor->{ReturnDelay}) )
        {
            Debug( "Returning to location ".$monitor->{ReturnLocation}."\n" );
            Suspend( $monitor );
            Return( $monitor );
            Resume( $monitor );
            $last_alarm = 0;
        }
    }
    usleep( SLEEP_TIME );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part:

```html
sub Track
{
 my $monitor = shift;
 my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
 my ( $detaint_x ) = $x =~ /^(\d+)$/; $x = $detaint_x;
 my ( $detaint_y ) = $y =~ /^(\d+)$/; $y = $detaint_y;

    my $ctrlCommand = ZM_PATH_BIN."/zmcontrol.pl -i ".$monitor->{Id};
 $ctrlCommand .= " --command=".($monitor->{CanMoveMap}?"moveMap":"movePseudoMap")." --xcoord=$x --ycoord=$y";
 executeShellCommand( $ctrlCommand );
```

```html
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
#
# ==========================================================================
#
# ZoneMinder Experimental PTZ Tracking Script, $Date: 2009-06-08 10:11:56 +0100 (Mon, 08 Jun 2009) $, $Revision: 2908 $
# Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Philip Coombes
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
#
# ==========================================================================
#
# This script is used to trigger and cancel alarms from external sources
# using an arbitrary text based format
#
use strict;
use bytes;

# ==========================================================================
#
# User config
#
# ==========================================================================

use constant SLEEP_TIME => 10000; # In microseconds

# ==========================================================================
#
# Don't change anything from here on down
#
# ==========================================================================

# Include from system perl paths only
use ZoneMinder;
use DBI;
use POSIX;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep );

$| = 1;

$ENV{PATH}  = '/bin:/usr/bin';
$ENV{SHELL} = '/bin/sh' if exists $ENV{SHELL};
delete @ENV{qw(IFS CDPATH ENV BASH_ENV)};

my $mid = 0;

sub Usage
{
 print( "
  Usage: zmtrack.pl -m <monitor>,--monitor=<monitor>]
  Parameters are :-
  -m<monitor>, --monitor=<monitor>   - Id of the monitor to track
  ");
 exit( -1 );
}   

if ( !GetOptions( 'monitor=s'=>\$mid ) )
{
 Usage();
}

logInit();
logSetSignal();

my ( $detaint_mid ) = $mid =~ /^(\d+)$/;
$mid = $detaint_mid;

print( "Tracker daemon $mid (experimental) starting at ".strftime( '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', localtime() )."\n" );

my $dbh = zmDbConnect();

my $sql = "select C.*,M.* from Monitors as M left join Controls as C on M.ControlId = C.Id where M.Id = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached( $sql ) or Fatal( "Can't prepare '$sql': ".$dbh->errstr() );

my $res = $sth->execute( $mid ) or Fatal( "Can't execute '$sql': ".$sth->errstr() );
my $monitor = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();

if ( !$monitor )
{
 print( "Can't find monitor '$mid'\n" );
 exit( -1 );
}
if ( !$monitor->{Controllable} )
{
 print( "Monitor '$mid' is not controllable\n" );
 exit( -1 );
}
if ( !$monitor->{TrackMotion} )
{
 print( "Monitor '$mid' is not configured to track motion\n" );
 exit( -1 );
}

if ( !$monitor->{CanMoveMap} )
{
 print( "Monitor '$mid' cannot move in map mode" );
 if ( $monitor->{CanMoveRel} )
 {
  print( ", falling back to pseudo map mode\n" );
 }
 else
 {
  print( "\n" );
  exit( -1 );
 }
}

Debug( "Found monitor for id '$monitor'\n" );
exit( -1 ) if ( !zmMemVerify( $monitor ) );

sub Suspend
{
 my $monitor = shift;
 zmMonitorSuspend( $monitor );
}

sub Resume
{
 my $monitor = shift;
 sleep( $monitor->{TrackDelay} );
 zmMonitorResume( $monitor );
}

sub Track
{
 my $monitor = shift;
 my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
 my ( $detaint_x ) = $x =~ /^(\d+)$/; $x = $detaint_x;
 my ( $detaint_y ) = $y =~ /^(\d+)$/; $y = $detaint_y;

    my $ctrlCommand = ZM_PATH_BIN."/zmcontrol.pl -i ".$monitor->{Id};
 $ctrlCommand .= " --command=".($monitor->{CanMoveMap}?"moveMap":"movePseudoMap")." --xcoord=$x --ycoord=$y";
 executeShellCommand( $ctrlCommand );
}

sub Return
{
 my $monitor = shift;

    my $ctrlCommand = ZM_PATH_BIN."/zmcontrol.pl -i ".$monitor->{Id};
 if ( $monitor->{ReturnLocation} > 0 )
 {
  $ctrlCommand .= " --command=presetGoto --preset=".$monitor->{ReturnLocation};
 }
 else
 {
  $ctrlCommand .= " --command=presetHome";
 }
 executeShellCommand( $ctrlCommand );
}

my $last_alarm = 0;
if ( ($monitor->{ReturnLocation} >= 0) )
{
 Suspend( $monitor );
 Return( $monitor );
 Resume( $monitor );
}

my $alarmed = undef;
while( 1 )
{
 if ( zmIsAlarmed( $monitor ) )
 {
  my ( $alarm_x, $alarm_y ) = zmGetAlarmLocation( $monitor );
  if ( $alarm_x >= 0 && $alarm_y >= 0 )
  {
   Debug( "Got alarm at $alarm_x, $alarm_y\n" );
   Suspend( $monitor );
   Track( $monitor, $alarm_x, $alarm_y );
   Resume( $monitor );
   $last_alarm = time();
   $alarmed = !undef;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  if ( logDebugging() && $alarmed )
  {
   print( "Left alarm state\n" );
   $alarmed = undef;
  }
  if ( ($monitor->{ReturnLocation} >= 0) && ($last_alarm > 0) && ((time()-$last_alarm) > $monitor->{ReturnDelay}) )
  {
   Debug( "Returning to location ".$monitor->{ReturnLocation}."\n" );
   Suspend( $monitor );
   Return( $monitor );
   Resume( $monitor );
   $last_alarm = 0;
  }
 }
 usleep( SLEEP_TIME );
}
```